# "done" function isn't working after moving from callbacks to promises for mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to reconfigure some code because mongoose no longer allows for callbacks. However, although I can find a user with findOne(), I am having trouble passing that user back to routes.js for further use.

Here is the old code:

From routes.js, where you can see the isLoggedIn function is not functioning properly:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));



// we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Here, req.user should print but it is undefined");
    console.log(req.user);
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Old code in passport.js:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        console.log("looking for user ");
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

Here is the new code in passport.js, where done() is not executing properly (i.e. the user is not getting returned, so authentication isn't working):

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    console.log(email + " logged in ");

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email })
    .then(user=>{
         if (!user){
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

         }
         if (!user.validPassword(password)){
             return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
         }
       req.user= user;
        return user;     
    })
    .then(user=>done(null,user))
    .catch((err)=>{
        return done(null, false);
req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

    });

}));
```

Comment: How are you verifying the issue? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I've added to the code in route.js to clarify the unexpected behavior

Comment: And you're saying it used to work with the callback version of Mongoose?

Comment: Why are you using `req.user= user;` in the new code when it wasn't in the old code?

Comment: That's right, it worked before. I tried that to intentionally set req.user. it doesn't work with or without it. I also tried returning `done(null, user)` instead of `return user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem here was related to running this code locally,
where cookies weren't saving properly because it wasn't running on https.

I had to change to something like this from [this site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

```
var app = express()
var sess = {
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {}
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
  sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies
}

app.use(session(sess))
```